# POSTing a file to an API with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post

My Goal: To submit some form data (message, category, photo) in my AngularJS app to an api. When the form submits, the file must be POSTed to the server first. A successful POST will return an object with a token. That token is then passed to another endpoint with the rest of the form data.

My Problem: I haven't been able to send the file to the api at all! I'm stuck as to where I am going wrong. Any advice anybody can give would be greatly appreciated.

HTML: my form uses ngSubmit to call a function.

```
<form name="submitAnIdeaForm" data-ng-submit="functions.submitForm(submitAnIdeaForm)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-top">

        <div class="header">
            <img data-ng-src="{{facebook.data.profile_picture.url}}" />
            <h1>I'd like to see a story about...</h1>
        </div>

        <textarea
            name="msg"
            placeholder="*Tell us about your idea"
            data-ng-model="form.msg"
            data-ng-class="{ 'error' : submitAnIdeaForm.msg.$invalid && submitAnIdeaForm.submitted}"
            required>
        </textarea>

        <div id="select-wrap">
            <label for="idea-select">Select a Category <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></label>

            <select
                id="idea-select"
                name="category"
                data-ng-model="form.category"
                required>

                    <option value="">Select A Category</option>
                    <option data-ng-repeat="cat in categories" value="{{cat.id}}">{{cat.name}}</option>

            </select>

            <p class="error" data-ng-show="submitAnIdeaForm.category.$invalid && submitAnIdeaForm.submitted">*Please select a category</p>
        </div>

        <input
            type="file"
            name="photo"
            data-ng-model="form.photo"
            valid-file
            required
        />
        <p class="error" data-ng-show="submitAnIdeaForm.photo.$invalid && submitAnIdeaForm.submitted">*Please choose a photo</p>

    </div>

    <div class="submit">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller JS: form is the raw object angular gives you

```
// Form Validation / Submit
submitForm: function(form) {
    if(form.$valid){
    // Post the idea
    Api.postIdea(form);

    // Send the user to the thank you page
    $location.path('/thank-you');
    }
}
```

Service JS: the code above calls postIdea() which is for posting all of the form data after. So first it calls this method, postFile, the one I am having trouble with.

```
postFile: function(form) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', form.photo);

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: this.api_base + '/upload',
    data: fd,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
    },
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    withCredentials: true
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    if(data.success){
    console.log("Success:", data, status, headers, config);
    } else {
    console.log("Error:", data, status, headers, config);
    }
});
}
```

Api Response

```
Error: Disallowed Key Characters. 200
```

Comment: Well, what's the trouble?

Comment: To quote my question - "My Problem: I haven't been able to send the file to the api at all! I'm stuck as to where I am going wrong. Any advice anybody can give would be greatly appreciated.". I assume though, that you are asking what specifically is going wrong. I get a responce back from the server saying success but it doesn't return any token.

Comment: updated my question with the responce from the api

Comment: Well the server seems to think everything went peachy.  Use Firebug or something like it to see what you are actually sending.  Compare what you are sending to the API spec for /upload. My guess: "file" is empty.  If so, you need to set a break point at the fd.append and see if `form` is valid.

Comment: the form is returning valid I'm actually getting "Error: Disallowed Key Characters. 200" from the response now. my earlyer report was when i was trying to pass it through an object... question response updated

Comment: What does "Pass it through an object" mean?

Comment: Reading other stackoverflow's, a dude was first passing the form data into an object `var xsrf = {filename: fd};` then `data:xsrf` ... i don't really know why i'm just desperate, trying anything I can. I assume the server accepted it because it was just getting a blank string so at least the data was 'valid'

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to read the specs for your server carefully.